# Dragon book exercise 4.2.3 f: Grammar for strings whose two halfs differ

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science

I can solve 4.2.3 a~e by myself, but f is too hard for me and I can't even find the answer using google.

> Design grammars for the following languages:
>
> (f) The set of all strings of 0s and 1s of the form xy, where x ≠ y and x and y are of the same length

Comment: Questions like this are a much better fit for [cs.se] and since that site supports MathJax, it's way easier to make the question and the answer more readable.

Comment: @rici , thanks for commenting. This is the first time I ask question in stackoverflow, sorry for the unclear statement and my poor english.

Comment: no worries. Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to read the help on [ask], particularly the section on homework questions,  and [What to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting thing about this language is its relationship with

`Ldup = { ωω | ω ∈ Σ*}`

which is the classic example of a language which is not context-free. But the language from the exercise

`Ldiff = { γζ | γ ≠ ζ ∧ γ ∈ Σ* ∧ ζ ∈ Σ* }`

has the property that

`Ldiff ⋃ Ldup ⋃ Lodd = Σ* and Ldup, Ldiff, Lodd  are disjoint.`

where

`Lodd = { ω | |ω| is odd ∧ ω ∈ Σ*}`

In other words, if you split a string into two equal-length parts, the two parts are either equal or unequal, and if you can't split the string that way, its length is odd.

L<sub>odd</sub> is clearly context free -- in fact, it is regular -- so the fact that L<sub>diff</sub> is context-free leads to the conclusion that the complement of a context-free language can be not context-free.

Given that, it's natural to think about L<sub>diff</sub> as being composed of the two equal-length pieces *γ* and *ζ*. But that frames the problem in a way that makes it difficult, if not impossible, to solve. As with many maths problems (and, I dare say, real-world problems), the solution has to start by reframing the problem to reveal its underlying simplicity. ("Thinking outside of the box", to use the famous cliché.)

Let's say that *γ* and *ζ* are both of length *n*. Since they are different, they must differ in at least one position. Let's say that *k* is such a position, so that *γ<sub>k</sub>* ≠ *ζ<sub>k</sub>*.

Now, let's try to characterise the pairs of strings which satisfy that constraint. All of the symbols other than the ones at position *k* are irrelevant, so what we end up with is:

`ΣkγkΣn-k-1 ΣkζkΣn-k-1`

That's obviously the same as

`ΣkγkΣk Σn-k-1ζkΣn-k-1`

and letting *j* = *n*−*k*−1, *a = γ<sub>k</sub>* and *b = ζ<sub>k</sub>*, we get

`ΣkaΣk ΣjbΣj, a ≠ b`

*j* and *k* and the two symbols *a* and *b* are all arbitrary in that expression. So in effect, we've described the set of strings which can be divided into two odd-length parts such that the symbols in the middle of the two parts differ. With binary strings, there are only two pairs of symbols which differ: `<0, 1>` and `<1, 0>`. So that leads to the following grammar:

```
W → 0 | 1               /* Wildcard */
A → 0 | W A W           /* Strings with a 0 in the middle */
B → 1 | W B W           /* Strings with a 1 in the middle */
S → A B | B A           /* Ldiff */
```

Comment: thanks very much!  
k0jk1j -> k0kj1j, this transformation is amazing.

Comment: @tiny: technically, my grammar is incorrect because `S`   should also recognise the empty string. Easy fix, though :-) A very similar approach works for recognizing strings of the form `1^i+1^j=1^(i+j)` and similar apparently arithmetic identities written in unary. (Try subtraction, or changing the `=` to `<`.) But it's a bit of a cheat, because the derivation is only vaguely related to the semantics.

Comment: intresting problems, especially the < variant. Hard to see the similarity if you don't tell me.

Comment: @tiny: The addition grammar is really simple. You start by reformulating `1^(i+j)` as `1^j 1^i`. (Since this question is sadly not on a site where MathJax works, you'll just have to pretend that `1^i` means `i` repetitions of the symbol `1`. In case that wasn't obvious.)

Comment: Actually I had figured it out.  
I meant that if you don't say those problems use similar trick  it would be difficult or imporssible for me to find the similarity.